# TextView with string and clickable text

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, textview

I am trying to use a TextView to display some text, part of the text needs to be clickable to open another activity.

Here is what I have so far:

```
        var byArtistNameView = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.ArtistName2);

        var ss = new SpannableString("By " + item.Artist.ArtistName);
        var clickableSpan = new MyClickableSpan();

        clickableSpan.Click = x => view.Context.StartActivity(new Intent(view.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));

        ss.SetSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.Gray), 0, 2, SpanTypes.ExclusiveExclusive);
        ss.SetSpan(clickableSpan, 3, ss.Length(), SpanTypes.ExclusiveExclusive);
        ss.SetSpan (new NoUnderlineSpan (), 3, ss.Length(), SpanTypes.ExclusiveExclusive);
        ss.SetSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(view.Resources.GetColor (Resource.Color.link_text)), 3, ss.Length(), SpanTypes.ExclusiveExclusive);


        byArtistNameView.TextFormatted = ss;
        byArtistNameView.MovementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.Instance;
```

---

```
        private class MyClickableSpan : ClickableSpan
        {
            public Action<View> Click;

            public override void OnClick(View widget)
            {
                if (Click != null)
                    Click(widget);
            }
        }
```

The text is blank / not visible if i set the MovementMethod to LinkMovementMethod.Instance, if i comment out this line then the text is visible and in the correct format, but just not clickable.

Any idea where I am going wrong here?

Thank You.

Comment: if you can share some screenshots of your textview we can be more helpful

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/ze4myda6d/ - this is a screenshot of how it looks side by side with/without MovemementMethod line commented out.

Comment: So if you set LinkMovementMethod, you can click there but the text is not shown?

Comment: no nothing is clicking.